# How can I permanently allow a firewall rule in OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, mac, firewall, osx-mountain-lion, growl

Since upgrading to OS X Mountain Lion, every time I restart my computer I am alerted

> Do you want the application "`Growl.app`" to accept incoming network connections?

[image: Picture.png]

Even though I click "`Allow`" this message continues to plague me upon restart.

[Silva says](http://silvanolte.com/blog/2011/01/18/do-you-want-the-application-to-accept-incoming-network-connections/) use `codesign -vvv` to verify the application is signed. It verifies:

```
$ codesign -vvv /Applications/Growl.app
/Applications/Growl.app: valid on disk
/Applications/Growl.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

It also seems that reinstalling the program does not help. How can I get rid of this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In System preferences Select Security & Privacy (Top row).  When you click on it, this will come up:
[image]

---

Click on the box that says Firewall options.  This is the next screen you will see:
[image]

---

Click on the + button in the middle left side and add Growl to the list.  This should alleviate your problem.

Comment: Nice. I was assuming Growl was automatically added to this when I clicked `Allow`. Thanks!

Comment: Just as an FYI, there is a nice little GUI front end for the Firewall called IceFloor ( http://www.hanynet.com/icefloor/ ).  It adds a little more capability, and if you know what you are doing with PF Firewalls, it's a nice way to manage it.  Just thought I'd mention it so that you're aware of it.

Comment: I have AirVideo in there but it still asks me for permission on every startup!